# Spark file system watcher not working on Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, apache-spark, filesystemwatcher

Two people tested [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) on their computers...

[image: Spark Download]

We downloaded the version of Spark prebuild for Hadoop 2.6, went to the folder `/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/`, created a "tmp" directory, and ran:

```
$ bin/run-example org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.HdfsWordCount tmp
```

I added arbitrary files `content1` and `content2dssdgdg` to that "tmp" directory.

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1467921704000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(content1,1)
(content2dssdgdg,1)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1467921706000 ms
```

Spark detected those files with the above terminal output on my Ubuntu 15.10 laptop, but not on my colleague's Windows 7 Enterprise laptop.

Does Spark's file system watcher not work on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John, I would suggest to use hadoop compiled binaries for 64 bits windows 7 hosted at https://github.com/karthikj1/Hadoop-2.7.1-Windows-64-binaries. To use this hadoop version you need to use spark version that is pre-built for user provided hadoop. Make sure to set SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH as mentioned in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html. Also put %HADOOP_HOME%\lib\native on PATH. Once setup, you need to follow steps 3.1,3.3,3.4 and 3.5 mentioned at https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows to start local HDFS. While running HdfsWordCount you need to pass hdfs:///tmp as directory path arg. All the best.